# spring data redis cluster pipeline support

Tags: spring, redis, cluster-computing

Is there a plan to support "pipelined" operations for the spring data redis library when connecting to redis clustered version. There is considerable performance differences between pipelined & non-pipelined operations. If there is no such plan what are other viable options?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Redis provides several RedisTemplate methods for executing commands in a pipeline. If you don’t care about the results of the pipelined operations, you can use the standard execute method, passing true for the pipeline argument. The executePipelined methods will execute the provided RedisCallback or SessionCallback in a pipeline and return the results. For example:

```
//pop a specified number of items from a queue
List<Object> results = stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(
  new RedisCallback<Object>() {
    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
      StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
      for(int i=0; i< batchSize; i++) {
        stringRedisConn.rPop("myqueue");
      }
    return null;
  }
});
```

The example above executes a bulk right pop of items from a queue in a pipeline. The results List contains all of the popped items. RedisTemplate uses its value, hash key, and hash value serializers to deserialize all results before returning, so the returned items in the above example will be Strings. There are additional executePipelined methods that allow you to pass a custom serializer for pipelined results.

Note that the value returned from the RedisCallback is required to be null, as this value is discarded in favor of returning the results of the pipelined commands.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline

Comment: I am aware of the pipelined method; the question is usage of pipelined for [cluster](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#cluster) When pipelined operation is used on a cluster enabled redis it throws an exception; which comes from JedisClusterConnection  `@Override
 public void openPipeline() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pipeline is currently not supported for JedisClusterConnection.");
 }` I am using version 1.7.7. I have looked at the code for 1.8, and 2.0 as well and it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: I have also tried by listing the master nodes on the cluster & then establishing a direct connection to the node & passing that as a callback connection factory to the rest template using pipelined execution. It goes through and saves few entries "sortedset" after that throws an exception `Redirect: slot 16034 to x.x.x.x:6379.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisMovedDataException: MOVED 16034 x.x.x.x:6379` which essentially means I am using a cluster; surprised how few entries got persisted? spring data redis experts any comments?

Comment: You may find this http://www.jacarrichan.com/Spring-Data-Redis-Add-Support-For-Redis-Cluster/ interesting

Answer (score 0):

Spring data redis does not supports the pipeline on cluster. So We can do it by our self in our application. If you use spring-data-redis and Jedis library.

So for that, we have to take Jedis Connection indirectly from Jedis Pool. Now if you only know keys of cluster then for that first you need to find out slot associated to key. You can get it by following way.

```
int slot = JedisClusterCRC16.getSlot(hKey);
```

Second, you can get JedisCluster connection by following way

```
JedisClusterConnection jedisClusterConnection = (JedisClusterConnection)stringRedisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getClusterConnection();
JedisCluster jedisCluster = jedisClusterConnection.getNativeConnection();
```

Now you have JedisCluster connection but it is not enough to get Jedis connection from Jedis pool. Because JedisCluster not exposing connection handler directly and `JedisSlotConnectionHandler` classing having method which returns the jedis connection from slot. so for that we have to copy the `BinaryJedisCluster` class from package `redis.clients.jedis` into our application with same class and package name and you have to add following method to expose connection handler.

```
public JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler getConnectionHandler() {
   return (JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler) this.connectionHandler;
}
```

Finally, you can able to get Jedis Connection by calling `getJedisConnectionFromSlot(slot)` method

```
JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler jedisClusterConnectionHandler = jedisCluster.getConnectionHandler();
Jedis connection = jedisClusterConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(slot);
Pipeline pipeline = connection.pipelined();
pipeline.somecommand....
pipeline.sync();
```

[Reference link](http://yagksjavablog.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-create-pipeline-in-rediscluster.html)